# Enyim Memcached issue over .Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, memcached

I have win 2008 R2 server with .net mvc project and other Ubuntu Linux with memchaed installed.

I have Eniym Memcached connector to memcached.

But when I try to run any memcached query I get:

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for enyim.com/memcached: Could not load type 'e.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection' from assembly 'Enyim.Caching'.

Enyim web.config section:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="e.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
<enyim.com>
    <memcached>
      <servers>
    <add address="10.10.10.10(not real ip, connect to other server)" port="11222" />
      </servers>
      <socketPool deadTimeout="00:00:10" />
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
```

Controller action:

```
using Enyim.Caching;
using Enyim.Caching.Memcached;
public string About()
        {
            MemcachedClient memCache = new MemcachedClient();
            memCache.Store(StoreMode.Set, "testkey", "testcontent");
            return "some string";
        }
```

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good example [here](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached/wiki/MemcachedClient-Configuration).

I think you want "Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection" where you currently have "e.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection"